# Parsing with AngleSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parsing, html-parsing, anglesharp

Writing programm to Parse some data from one website using `AngleSharp`. Unfortunately I didn't find any documentation and it makes understanding realy hard.

1. How can I by using `QuerySelectorAll` get only link? I'm getting now just all things `<a ...>...</a>` with `Name of article`.

`<a href="http://kinnisvaraportaal-kv-ee.postimees.ee/muua-odra-tanaval-kesklinnas-valmiv-suur-ja-avar-k-2904668.html?nr=1&amp;search_key=69ec78d9b1758eb34c58cf8088c96d10" class="object-title-a text-truncate">1. Name of artucle</a>`

The method I'm using now:

```
var items = document.QuerySelectorAll("a").Where(item => item.ClassName != null && item.ClassName.Contains("object-title-a text-truncate"));
```

2. In the previous example I also used  ClassName.Contains("object-name"), but if we deal with table cells, there are no any class. As I understand to parse right element maybee I must use some info about parent also. So here is the question, how can I get this '4' value from tabble cell?

....`<th class="strong">Room</th>
<td>4</td>`....

Comment: Please clarify your problem. It's hard to find a question in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question.
Here is an example that you can extract the link address.
This a [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105259/getting-href-property-with-anglesharp-linq-query) of another Stackoveflow post that is related.

```cs
var source = @"<a href='http://kinnisvaraportaal-kv-ee.postimees.ee/muua-odra-tanaval-kesklinnas-valmiv-suur-ja-avar-k-2904668.html?nr=1&amp;search_key=69ec78d9b1758eb34c58cf8088c96d10' class='object-title-a text-truncate'>1. Name of artucle</a>";
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var doc = parser.Parse(source);

var selector = "a";

var menuItems = doc.QuerySelectorAll(selector).OfType<IHtmlAnchorElement>();

foreach (var i in menuItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.Href);
}
```

For your Second question, you can check the example on the documention, here is the [Link](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp#simple-demo) and below is the code sample:

```cs
// Setup the configuration to support document loading
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
// Load the names of all The Big Bang Theory episodes from Wikipedia
var address = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Big_Bang_Theory_episodes";
// Asynchronously get the document in a new context using the configuration
var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address);
// This CSS selector gets the desired content
var cellSelector = "tr.vevent td:nth-child(3)";
// Perform the query to get all cells with the content
var cells = document.QuerySelectorAll(cellSelector);
// We are only interested in the text - select it with LINQ
var titles = cells.Select(m => m.TextContent);
```